# Make RelativeLayout to fit all screen size

Tags: java, android, layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to modify my Relative Layout to fit all the screen size. I understood that my problem was that I was manually setting the margin for every single element on the screen, because it was easier to set on the editor in Android Studio, but obviously, as soon as I tried the app on another device the elements were in a mess. Now, I modified it by using the "match_parent" and wrap_content commands to make it more flexibly, and this is the result when I try it on a Pixel C:
[image]

The problem is when I change device, because for example if I try It on a Galaxy Tab this is the result:
[image]

This is the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/slidelinearlayout"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main2">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/upperLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/slideimg"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="150dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txttitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Senza nome"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/upperTableHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
            android:text="Table Header here"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/tl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/t2"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_item_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="  Flessibilità"
                android:textColor="#030101"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/f_item_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_item_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_2"
                android:layout_width="202dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="  Fluidità"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fl_item_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_item_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="  Originalità"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/o_item_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_item_4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="  Elaborazione"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/el_item_4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_item_5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="  Titolo"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t_item_5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/upperLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lowerTableHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Table Header here"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/tl_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tl">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_item_6"
            android:layout_width="222dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t1_item_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="    Tempo di reazione"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tempo_item_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_item_7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t2_item_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="    Tempo di completamento"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tempo_item_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tr_item_8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/table_row_bg"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/n_cancellature"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="    Numero cancellature"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/n_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_cell_bg"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#070404"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your current question, but in the future consider using ConstraintLayout to avoid similar problems. With that layout your hierarchy is flat and everything can be relevant to the screen, so everything resizes and adjust based on the different screen sizes.

Comment: Do **not** align elements in your layout using attributes such as `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` and `marginLeft` and `marginRight`. You're hardcoding its position, so when it displays it onto a different device, it'll try to position itself there, but of course, both the resolution and the space will decrease or increase accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SDP to set the size of controls or text for different devices.

[image]

An android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

Link - https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Answer (score -1):

you can create Different layout directory in res

and Design ui exclusively for that screen size

Android automatically detects which size must to use

like : layout (this is default and its for all devices)
       layout-sw600 (for 7 and 8 inch screens)
       layout-sw720 (for 10 ,11 and 12 screens)

for more info watch [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)